# Finding the decimal exponent based on the index of a for-loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, d3.js, decimal

The user chooses a number and then d3.js should display as many circles.
I have an array that is used to assigned color to the circles:

```
var color =["red","blue", "yellow", "orange",....., ]
```

● If the user choose 593,  the first 500 circle should be red (`color[0]`) , the next 90 should be blue (`color[1]`) and the last 3 (`color[2]`) should be yellow Because

```
593= 500+90+3 = 5*10^2+9*10^1+3*10^0
```

or 
with

```
var number = 593
var number_as_array = number.toString().split('');
```

Then

```
593 = 5*number_as_array[0]*10^number_as_array.length-0-1 + 9*number_as_array[1]*10^number_as_array.length-1-1+ 3*number_as_array[2]*10^number_as_array.length-2-1
```

● If the user choose 4168 the first 4000 circle should be red, the next 100 should be blue, the next 60 yellow and the last 8 orange

To assign the color to each circle I use  to create an array of JS object build with a for loop

```
var data=[]
for (index =0; index< number; index++){
circle= {};
        circle.cx = circle_x;
        circle.cy = circle_y;
        circle.color = color[????]
        data.push(circle);
```

How can I assign the color to `circle.color` based on the condition above ?

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. It seems you just need to loop over the *number_as_array* array using say *i* as the counter, then assign *color[i]* to the related *circle.color* property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to diminish from the other answer, here's an alternative approach.

Taking a given total number of circles, it checks to see how many significant digits of the total are required (rounding down) so that any given index is less than rounded total.

I'm not sure if that makes complete sense, so I'll use an example:

If there are 132 circles in total:

- Indexes 0 through 99 will be less than 100 (132 rounded down with one significant digit).
- Indexes 100 through 129 will be less than 130 (132 rounded down with two significant digits).
- Indexes 130 and 131 will be less than 132 (132 with all significant digits).

Here's a quick demonstration (rows are 50 circles across):

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",510)
  .attr("height",510);
  
var n = 377;

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
.range(["steelblue","orange","crimson","lawngreen","pink"])

var digits = Math.floor(Math.log10(n));

var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(d3.range(n))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx",function(d,i) { return i%50 * 10 + 5 })
  .attr("cy",function(d,i) { return Math.floor(i/50) * 10 + 5 })
  .attr("r",5)
  .attr("fill", function(d,i) {
    var exp = digits;
    while (i < Math.floor(n/Math.pow(10,digits-exp))*Math.pow(10,digits-exp)) {
      exp--;
    }
    return color(exp);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var color = ["red","orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"];
var circleCount = "4192"; // use string
var length = circleCount.length;
var counter = [];
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var digit = circleCount.substring(i, i+1);
    var exponent = length - i - 1;
    var number = digit * Math.pow(10, exponent);
    counter.push(number); // might have to use .unshift instead of .push
}
console.log(counter);
for (var i = 0; i < counter.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < counter[i]; j++) {
        drawCircle(color[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect case for using D3's [Threshold Scales](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#threshold-scales): you give it N numbers where you want breaks between the colors, and N+1 colors to return for any input value. Here is the example from the docs:

> ```
> var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
>     .domain([0, 1])
>     .range(["red", "white", "green"]);
>
> color(-1);   // "red"
> color(0);    // "white"
> color(0.5);  // "white"
> color(1);    // "green"
> color(1000); // "green"
> ```

So the challenge for your case is how to convert (for instance) your example input of 593 into the array of the two numbers [500, 590]:

```
var sinput = 593 + ""; // make the input a string
var digits = sinput.split("").slice(0, -1); // use all digits but the last one
var breaks = digits.map((d, i, a) =>
    +(a.slice(0, i+1).join("")) * Math.pow(10, a.length-i)
);

var colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "orange"];
var tScale = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .domain(breaks)
    .range(colors);
```

Anything < 500 maps to "red", from 500 - 589 maps to "blue", and ≥ 590 maps to "yellow". The additional range color ("orange") is not used, unless a 4-digit number is used as input.

*Note: this logic assumes the input number will have at least 2-digits.*

You can now assign the color at the time of creating the circle -- rather than pre-populating it in the data array -- using syntax like `.attr("color", (d, i) => tScale(i))`

Answer (score 1):

The other approaches seem overly complex. You can split the number into its digits, then create the required 10^digitIndex circles with colour based on the index. I've included a line to check that the number isn't too big.

```js
function mapColors(num) {
  var color =['red','blue', 'yellow', 'orange'];
  
  // If the number is longer than the color array, return undefined
  if ((''+num).length > color.length) return;
  
  return (''+num).split('').reduce(function (acc, n, i, arr) {
    for (var j=n*Math.pow(10, arr.length-i-1); j; --j) {
      acc.push({'color':color[i]});
      // Add more circle properties here
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

console.log(mapColors(23));
```